# how to use 1 array for multiple views?

Tags: objective-c

I am writing an app and having some doubt while doing it. I save data in NSUserDefault. And I have 4 views which is: update view, delete view, adding view and a display view. Since data in NSUserDefault is not mutable. So what I do is to overwrite the data.

I am thinking of using one array to store all the data. Let's say I call it as controlArray. 
But How can I carray the data in the controlArray to different view? for example: i remove an item in the controlArray in the delete view, then when I switch to the display view, that item should not be seen anymore. Do the same thing for other view. Can I do that? please tell me, give me some hint.

Thank u so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to save the Array in the AppDelegate. You can access it from everywhere and make changes to it.

Comment: nice, it works, however, I would like to try with the single ton. I created a class call Books. I make an NSMutableArray in there. Then in other view i do: Books *item = [Books new]; then [item.array addObject@"123"] but nothing happens. Even I NSlog the class of item.array still giving null. Can you tell me why please?